# How can I connect a 10/3 range to an old 8/2 circuit?

Tags: 240v, range

This was working fine, but I had to move the range, and I didn't pay attention when I disconnected it. There is an 8/2 in the wall (black white bare) and the range has 10/3 (red black white bare).
I need this back in use.
What if I use wall black to range black, wall white to range red, and then wall bare (ground) to range ground and white? After all, don't white and bare go to the same place in the breaker box?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the junction box where the 8/2 cable ends?

Comment: "*What if I ground the range's neutral leg and use the white source for the range's red leg?*" The proper way do it is to wire it up the same as it was before, not some other way. It was working fine so it should work fine again if you get it back to the way it was.

Comment: If I knew how it was wired, I probably wouldn't be asking how to wire it.

Answer (score 2):

No. You cannot connect a device neutral to ground.  If the range has no 120 volt components such as as a light or fan, you may be able to cap and not connect the neutral. Check the installation guide for the range.

Comment: I suspect the OP has a legacy 3-wire range circuit, which'll need more details both in the question and the answer to handle...

Comment: Legacy 3 wire (black white bare) is right.

Comment: @jsureke -- can you *please* post photos of the inside of the box you're connecting to the existing 8/2 at? We need to see inside there to get a good handle on what your options *are*

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I won't have a picture until the weekend. In the box is a black wire, a white wire, and a bare wire. On the stove there is a black wire, a red wire, a white wire, and a bare wire.

Comment: @jsureke -- is the incoming bare wire from the box a solid wire, or several strands of wire that fan out to around the edge of the incoming cable?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel It's solid. I believe all 3 are. On the range they are stranded except for the bare ground.